# Unable to Compile Material in Angular 4 , gives :/material" has no exported member 'MaterialModule

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I am creating  new Angular 4 app using Material UI Framework. 
I followed the steps given as : https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started  .

But when i am doing 'npm start' , it fails to compile and says  :
`ERROR in /home/programoholic/workspace/heroapp/src/app/app.module.ts (3,10): Module '"/home/programoholic/workspace/heroapp/node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MaterialModule'`.

Error Screenshot :

[when compiling getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9aLF.png)

this  is my Package.Json file :

```
{
  "name": "heroapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.11",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.35",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

Please can any body let me know what problem is causing this error ? 
And what is the best solution for this ?
Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to import `MaterialModule`, when instead you should be importing the individual items `MdCheckboxModule` or `MdInputModule` etc...

Comment: Please read material changelog https://github.com/angular/material2/releases/tag/2.0.0-beta.11

Comment: Thanks guys... I created a new ngModule which imports all the material components. then Added the module to app.module.ts . Working fine now. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MaterialModule` was depreciated in version **2.0.0-beta.3** and it has been removed completely in version **2.0.0-beta.11**. See this [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) for more details. Please go through the breaking changes.

> MaterialModule has been removed and is no longer available. As noted
>   in the changelog for beta.3, an aggregate module like MaterialModule
>   prevents tools from being able to treeshake unused components and
>   modules.

You need to include individual material component modules in order to use them in your app.

Comment: Thanks.. Working fine now :)

Answer (score 1):

Import the individual modules for Angular material like this

```
import { matButtonModule,matCardModule,matMenuModule,matToolbarModule,matIconModule,matSelectModule } from '@angular/material';
```